# How to set session cookies to http only in php.ini file

Tags: php, session-cookies, httponly

In my Ubuntu server, I modified the php.ini file to try and set my session cookies to http only to be more secure. I modified the line in the php.ini file from  `session.cookie_httponly =` to `session.cookie_httponly = 1`, but still no success. When I view the inspect the page in chrome, my session cookies are still not flagged httponly. Are there any other steps I am missing to set the httpOnly flag on my session cookies? I've also tried adding `ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);` before starting sessions, but still no success.

Comment: Did you try adding it to apache conf, or htaccess instead? Also, when in chrome, I assume (or maybe not?) that you purged the cookie before testing it again to see if a new cookie made is set with the http flag?

Comment: Are you restarting the Apache server after configuring php.ini?

Comment: By purging the cookie, do you mean destroying it then starting it again? If so then yes, still no success. @IncredibleHat

Comment: Just tried that, but still doesn't seem to work @solarc

Comment: Nevermind, got it working now. Thanks

Comment: Curious what the solution was (in case this happens to other people). Might be nice to add an answer even if its your own question ;)